# Which of the given sets are connected

Tags: connectedness, proof-verification

Which of the following sets are connected?

a. The set $\{f(x, y)\in R:xy = 1\}$

b. The set of all symmetric matrices in $M_n(R).$

c. The set of all orthogonal matrices in $M_n(R).$

---

My attempt:

a) False ($(x,y)→x$ is continuous under which the image is $R-\{0\}$,disconnected, but connectedness is invariant under continuous map),

b) True (For $A,B$ symmetric $(1-t)A+tB~∀~0≤t≤1$ is symmetric whence the set is path connected),

c) False ($\det$ is continuous under which the image is $\{-1, 1\}$ disconnected, but connectedness is invariant under continuous map)

Am I correct?

Comment: These proofs are correct and all very elegant. For (b), it holds more generally that every vector subspace is connected: it is homeomorphic to $\bf{R}^n$ for some $n$ by a linear map.

Comment: @Yuval: Thanks so much!!

Comment: What does the $f$ in the first set mean?